# Extracting XML Child Node values based on a parent

Tags: xml, parsing, entity, external, xmlstarlet

I have a rather large xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">
<tv source-info-url="http://blah blah blah.com/" source-info-name="blah.com" generator-info-name="zap2xml" generator-info-url="zap2xml@gmail.com">
                        <channel id="IX.XXXXXX.blah.com">
                                <display-name>WCBS</display-name>
                                <display-name>2 WCBS</display-name>
                                <display-name>2</display-name>
                                <icon src="https://blah blah blah.png" />
                        </channel>
                        <channel id="IX.XXXXX.blah.com">
                                <display-name>WCBSDT</display-name>
                                <display-name>2 WCBSDT</display-name>
                                <display-name>2</display-name>
                                <icon src="https://blah blah blah.png" />
                        </channel>
                        <channel id="IX.XXXXX.blah.com">
                                <display-name>WNBC</display-name>
                                <display-name>4 WNBC</display-name>
                                <display-name>4</display-name>
                                <icon src="https://blah blah blah.png" />
                        </channel>
                        .....
    </tv>
```

For now, I just want to loop through the .xml, extract the channel id TAG value, then extract the first and third "display-name" tag values, and display them per channel based on that id.

I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file='/path/to/xml/file/file.xml'
cat $file | while read line ; do
        if [[ $line == *"<channel id="* ]]; then
        channelid=$(echo $line|awk -F'"' '{print $2}')
        channelnum=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//channel[@id='$channelid']//display-name[3]" -n $file)
        callsign=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//channel[@id='$channelid']//display-name[1]" -n $file)
        clear
        echo "Here are the details for channel id: $channelid"
        echo ""
        echo "Channel Number is: $channelnum"
        echo "Channel Call Sign is: $callsign"
        echo ""
        sleep 2
        fi
done
```

which DOES do what I want, but the entire process is slowed down because it keeps trying to lookup the external entity links for every channel it encounters - outputting this:

```
Here are the details for channel id: IX.XXXXX.blah.com

Channel Number is: 2
Channel Call Sign is: WCBS

/path/to/the/epg.xml:2.30: failed to load external entity "/path/to/the/script/xmltv.dtd"
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">
                                ^
/path/to/the/xmlfile.xml:2.30: failed to load external entity "/path/to/the/script/xmltv.dtd"
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">
```

How can I suppress these lookups?  I just want to parse these values.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I suppress these lookups?

You can first use the [xmlstarlet `fo` (format) command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139569312) to remove the DOCTYPE declaration.

You should also be able to get all of the values you need just by using the [xmlstarlet `sel` (select) command](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416) and XPath. Trying to cat the file, read lines, and parse with regex can be fragile.

Full example...

```sh
#!/bin/bash

file='/path/to/the/file.xml'

xmlstarlet fo -D $file | \
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "/tv/channel" \
    -v "concat('Here are the details for channel id: ', @id)" -nl -nl \
    -v "concat('  Channel Number is: ', display-name[3])" -nl \
    -v "concat('  Channel Call Sign is: ', display-name[1])" -nl -nl
```

Output...

```
Here are the details for channel id: IX.XXXXXX.blah.com

  Channel Number is: 2
  Channel Call Sign is: WCBS

Here are the details for channel id: IX.XXXXX.blah.com

  Channel Number is: 2
  Channel Call Sign is: WCBSDT

Here are the details for channel id: IX.XXXXX.blah.com

  Channel Number is: 4
  Channel Call Sign is: WNBC
```

Comment: This is great @Daniel.  Definitely fast and a good example on use.  

But, how can I also capture the id, channel, and sign as variables together (i.e. - a "record" if you will) as I was doing?  

This was the reason for the line by line/regex routine....  Your example parses everything wonderfully, but it dumps out the results as a BATCH rather than as a one-by-one record/row.

Comment: @AMPSYS - can you add an example of the required output to your question?

Comment: I want to capture the channel number and call sign as variables that MATCH their parent channel ID.  I'm only echoing output right now to test that capture, but the real purpose would be to manipulate other files or create/update records in a database.  Does that make more sense?